# Ethers how to import Interface class

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

Been looking at Interface class of Ethers library
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Interface--creating

and would like to test it like below, but not sure how to import this class and FormatTypes from Ethers. I get now "Interface is not defined" using

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
const iface = new Interface(humanReadableAbi);
jsonAbi = iface.format(FormatTypes.json);
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonAbi), null, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Still getting grasp with JS and how libraries are structured. Found it out by inspecting code of ethers library. So for this it is

```
import { FormatTypes, Interface } from "@ethersproject/abi";
```